# How to sort rails model by has_many last active field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models:

`User` has_many `Subscription`.

My user model has a function called `active_subscription`.

```
def active_subscription
  subscriptions.where(active: true).last
end
```

I would like to be able to sort my user's by this active subscription's `type_name` field. I need to use the active subscription because only the last active subscription is rendered in my views.

I have this written:

```
includes(:subscriptions).order("subscriptions.type_name #{sort_order}")
```

But, this isn't taking into account the active subscription.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your User model? When you say User has_many Subscription; I am hoping you have it something like this in `User` model: `has_many :subscriptions`.
Also, you say you aren't getting active subs; are you getting any subs? You aren't using that function you defined in the model.

Answer (score 0):

using scope probably can help, below is sample for your problem

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord

  scope :active_subscription, lambda { where('active = ?',true)}
  scope :type_name_order,     lambda { |q| order("type_name :q", q: "#{q}") }

end

User.subscriptions.active_subscription.type_name_order('DESC').last

@users = Subscription.joins(:user).active_subscription.type_name_order('DESC').select('users.username','subscriptions.*')

@users.first.username # you will get first username

# you can also combine with last 

@users = Subscription.joins(:user).active_subscription.type_name_order('DESC').select('users.*','subscriptions.*').last(10)

# in my above example i'm using * to select all column of table users
# for example your table users has gender column you can use

puts @users.first.gender 

# if table users and subscriptions have same column name for example subscriptions.active and users.active then you should use alias 'AS' in select
```

Comment: But this returns a subscription. I need to return a list of ordered User objects, ordered by their `active_subscription.type_name`

Comment: I just add another information , please see my answer above